# PHP Laravel foreach does not modify the value

Tags: php, foreach, pass-by-reference, laravel-5.4

I am writing code to sort eloquent relationship instance in the parent.

```
$categories = CategoryMain::with('subs')->get();
    foreach($categories as &$category){
        $category->sub = $category->subs->sortBy('name');
    }
```

I get the correct arrangement inside the foreach loop, which i verify by doing die(var_dump());,

However, once it is outside, it seems like it is not changed at all.
Why is it happening?

Comment: please show mode code with the $categories.

Comment: those are the only code..
What i want to achieve is sorting the subs, which is already correct in the foreach, but after it finishes, it does not modify the value @KrisRoofe

Comment: You aren't saving the models, so nothing will change

Comment: `$category->save()`

Comment: `sub` vs `subs`. Are you sure you've spelled these correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this and see what is the output:

```
$categories = CategoryMain::with('subs')->get();

$counter = 0;
foreach($categories as $category) {
    $categories[$counter]->sub = $category->subs->sortBy('name');
    $counter++
}
//output the data of catgories
dd($categories);
```

Comment: this way will work i think..
but why we cannot directly change it using the iterator on for loop?

Comment: The reason for using an iterator with foreach loop is to save the new values that are generated inside the loop to the original Collection object. The $category variable is just a local variable which has scope limited to the loop itself